# BackgroundWorker that uses HttpClient async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, backgroundworker, asp.net-4.5

I have used in the past the `BackgroundWorker` in a Windows Form application.
For my new exercise I need to use `async` methods inside the worker and I am getting a little bit confused about that.

This is my code structure. In the form load event I am creating the `BackgroundWorker` object and setup events

```
private void fMain_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( bw_DoWork );
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler( bw_ProgressChanged );
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( bw_RunWorkerCompleted );
}
```

When the user click a button I am starting the worker

```
private void btnGenerate_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    pbCounter.Visible = true;
    btnGenerate.Enabled = false;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync( settings );
}
```

And this is the worker code

```
private async void bw_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e ) {
    try {
        for ( int ix = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {
            using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
                [???? how to call and wait here ????]
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync( "endpoint", new StringContent( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( formContent ), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) );
            }

            //The counter will keep track of your process
            Application.DoEvents();
            int percentage = ix * 100 / settings.TotalRuns;
            bw.ReportProgress( percentage );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex ) {
        MessageBox.Show( ex.Message, "Gift Creator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `BackgroundWorker` plays well with async-await. You should probably use something else (or build it).

Comment: That can't work. If you make the `DoWork` handler `async` and use `await` inside, the method returns there and the background worker will be finished. I think you don't need a background worker when using async, but wil have to think a while about how reporting progress then.

Comment: @RenéVogt: right. I was thinking to throw the background worker away. However I like very much the way it handles progress notification. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could simply put your `for` loop as it is (including `await`) into your button handler and update the progress bar from there (for each iteration). I don't know the `HttpClient` class and if it reports progress. But it seems you wanted to show the loop 's progress only anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `async` and `await` there is no need for a background worker. In fact, your background worker would not work because the control is given back to the caller when you use `await`. And when the `DoWork` handler returns control to its caller, the background worker will terminate and not continue its remainnig tasks.

So I would make the button handler `async` and do the http requests there:

```
    private async void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int totalRuns = 5;
        pbCounter.Visible = true;
        pbCounter.Minimum = 0;
        pbCounter.Maximum = totalRuns;
        pbCounter.Value = 0;
        btnGenerate.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            for ( int i = 1; i <= totalRuns; i++ ) 
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
                    await client.PostAsync( "endpoint", new StringContent( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( formContent ), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) );
                pbCounter.Value = i;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message, "Gift Creator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
        }

        btnGenerate.Enabled = true;
    }
```

So this handler gives back the control to the caller (to say it over-simplified: the UI) while waiting for the http request. When the request is finished, the execution is continued at the `pbCounter.Value = i` line - and on the UI thread! So you can safely update the progress bar, because you're not doing it from another thread.

I hope this helps you. Note that I set the `pbCounter.Maximum` to the number of loops you're about to run, so you don't need to calculate the percentage.